# Extjs: how to send empty timefield?

Tags: extjs, send, timefield

I'm developing Extjs form and have to send all field, also empty fields. It works for all types of fields only timefield is not send. Here an example with datefield and timefield.
Why do they behavior differently? Which config should I use to send empty timefield? Preferred as variable name with empty string as value.  Do you have an idea?

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
standardSubmit: true,
items: [{
    fieldLabel: 'Datefield',
    format: 'Y-m-d',
    name: 'Datefield',
    // value: '2015-01-01',
    xtype: 'datefield'
},{
    fieldLabel: 'Timefield',
    format: 'H:i:s',
    name: 'Timefield',
    // value: '16:00:00',
    xtype: 'timefield'
}],
buttons: [{
    text: 'Submit',
    formBind: true,
    handler: function(){
        this.up('form').getForm().submit({
            url: 'http://yourfavoriteurl',
            standardSubmit: true,
            method: 'POST' // 'GET'
        });
    }
}] 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The timefield was developed that way on purpose because it is a normal thing to omit time from queries.

If you want this field to behave like the datefield when empty, add this override:

```
Ext.define('Ext.view.override.TimeField',{
     override: 'Ext.form.field.Time',

     getSubmitValue: function() {
        var me = this,
            format = me.submitFormat || me.format,
            value = me.getValue();

        return value ? Ext.Date.format(value, format) : "";
    }
});
```

Comment: It's strange for me, that from all types of fields only timefield doesn't send empty content. To not send empty content is a standard behavior of HTML checkbox only and there is a suitable option in Extjs: uncheckedValue and it could be set with empty string.
Fields in forms are used to input data, what queries do you mean?

Comment: I meant SQL queries, sometimes more often than not, time is optional and doesn't need to be sent as for other fields you might want to submit empty strings. But if you feel that this is BUG and shouldnt behave this way, open a ticket with sencha...they are very responsive.